# Get file upload as string (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<h4>Upload CSV File:</h4> 
<%= form_tag(import_patients_path, :method =>'post', :multipart => true) %>
<%= file_field_tag 'csvfile' %>
<br />
<%= submit_tag "Upload CSV Data" %>
</form>
```

From the controller I simply need to get the file as a string. Is there an easy way to do this? (I don't need to save the file anywhere)

Comment: +1 I can't believe more people didn't find this useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
csv_data = params[:uploaded_file].read
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that you should replace :uploaded_file with the file field tag... For the example in the question:
csv_data = params[:csvfile].read